# Wrong data on Youtube API

Tags: python

I am trying to retrieve videos details from Youtube. However, my code is not returning the data I am expecting. In fact, I don't even know what I am retrieving. I am not sure if my problem is the `channel ID` or just the way I am calling the API.
Here is what I am doing:

```
# These variables above are in the youtubevar.py files where I keep my variables
apikey ='xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
channelid='UCWnfDPdZw6A23UtuBpYBbAg'  # this supposed to be james charles channel
pageToken=''

url='https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key='+apikey+'&channelId='+channelid+'&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=200'+pageToken

=======================  == = == = = == = = = = =
# Main file
import requests
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
%pylab inline
from youtubevar import*

#Here im calling the API 
response=requests.get(url).json()

# having a look of what I get 
print (response)   # Not the data I expect
```

The according to the code, I am supposed to get the details of the video in descending order. SO I should get the latest one first but I am getting some turkish there.

```
 Sample output 
 'kind': 'youtube#searchListResponse',
 'etag': 'Baz6gP84Rb-IaJRTFB6BTXHSOOc',
 'nextPageToken': 'CDIQAA',
 'regionCode': 'GB',
 'pageInfo': {'totalResults': 1000000, 'resultsPerPage': 50},
 'items': [{'kind': 'youtube#searchResult',
 'etag': 'Wvdfq24D5OzYpzICCND0Z9TypT8',
'id': {'kind': 'youtube#video', 'videoId': '5YiV7OyzjH0'},
 'snippet': {'publishedAt': '2021-08-25T08:00:01Z',
'channelId': 'UCcNqSmZeXNxccDzVYEf7zpg',
'title': 'TUGAY GÖK A WAY OUT (AHA YAKALAN DIK !!!!)',
'description': 'Tugay Gök Nonolive https://www.nonolive.com/tugaygok Tugay Gök Youtube https://www.youtube.com/user/TheMaraztr Tugay Gök İnstagram ...',
'thumbnails': {'default': {'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5YiV7OyzjH0/default.jpg',
  'width': 120,
  'height': 90},
 'medium': {'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5YiV7OyzjH0/mqdefault.jpg',
  'width': 320,
  'height': 180},
 'high': {'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5YiV7OyzjH0/hqdefault.jpg',
  'width': 480,
  'height': 360}},
'channelTitle': 'Tugay Gök Fan',
'liveBroadcastContent': 'none',
'publishTime': '2021-08-25T08:00:01Z'}},
{'kind': 'youtube#searchResult',
```

Comment: Can you please show what you are receiving?

Comment: @Herc01 : can you share the output How it is coming

Comment: @OneCricketeer done - details from the first video . I even got some chinese there on the third or fourth video I believe

Comment: @codeholic24 - done - details from the first video-  which is nothing to do with James Charles

Comment: The problem is probably that you're using the /search endpoint rather than /channels for a specific channel https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs